# Animate scrolltop with jquery is a bug

Tags: jquery, html

```
var target = $('#div_target');
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1);

var target = $('#div_target');
$('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: target.offset().top
}, 1800);
```

I'm using this code to animate the scroll.
Using 1ms works but putting 1800ms does not work.
It goes beyond the element. Why!? Thanks!

Comment: can you add your html or a relevant fragment?

Comment: the code is this. link to page: http://humanitysaude.com.br
click 'fale conosco' in menu. with browser in 360px for mobile, don't work.